# In-line image and h (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, inline

I want to align in-line a profile image and its username inline. Here's the code:

```
<div id="post">
    <div class="proPic">
        <img title="proPic" alt="Profile Picture" src="">
    </div>
    <h3>Username</h3>
    <p>Text post</p>
</div>
```

What's the best way to do this? I'd like to see both HTML and CSS methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using less code than you have already ;)

```css
body {
font-family: arial;
}

.profile {
width: 25%;
float: right;
background: pink;
}

.profile h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 14px;
min-height: 50px; /*Just for demo*/
}

.content {
width: 70%;
float: left;
background: #ccc;
min-height: 200px; /*Just for demo*/
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
 <div class="profile">
 <img title="proPic" alt="Profile Picture" src="">
 <h3>Username</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  Text post
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, actually i have a rule for profile pictures to set them to specified pixels. Shouldn't that stay the same?

Comment: Sure just add: #post img {width: 100px } for example

Comment: More "real world" I imagine you would add a class "profilePic" to the image and a style .profilePic {width: 100px; height: 100px } to your style sheet (for example)

Comment: thanks. The p (post text) and even the username are still unaligned. how do i align them better? for example the p under the img and h?

Comment: OK, post an image in the question showing how you'd like it

Comment: I'd just like something like Facebook posts, Image, username on its right and the post under both of them

Comment: I edited the answer to a rough guess of what you are after, I hope it gives you the inspiration to get it exactly how you need it :)